# Setting up a private GIT Repo

Tags: linux, fedora, git

I am new to git and I want to setup a private git repo for my projects. We are two guys working on the project and have a shared connection. I am using fedora 14 and want to setup git on the same machine that I use. Also my partner should be able to access and commit changes to the same as we both would be sharing the code.

I went through some of tut online but believe me I didn't get a clue. So if anyone can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get out of the CVS/SVN mentality that you need to "set something up".

To start using git, just create a local repo using `git init`. That's it.

Your coworkers can clone your repo using git clone, assuming they have ssh access to your machine. Then you can pull from each others repo whenever it is needed.

As your needs grow, you will maybe want to move to a more CVSy workflow with a centralized server. In that case, simply create a third clone (using --bare since you don't need the files to be actually checked out on this repo) on the server, and set your repos to use it as the origin. Then you can "push" to it, which is the equivalent of a CVS/SVN commit operation.